# Python, problems with using an API to login and authenticate

Tags: python, api, authentication

**Edit:** 
I found a solution, I parsed the Key and Token through

```
MyKey = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Key'])
MyToken = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Token'])
```

from the LoginResponse and then added it to the RegisterHeaders

```
RegisterHeaders = {
'accept': "application/json",
'AOToken': MyToken,
'AOKey': MyKey,
'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
}
```

***Original question:***

Any kind of help is really appreciated! I need help with authenticating myself through Python. I use an API to get some json functions I can call on a website. The login-part works, but it comes up with errors when I try to authenticate. I use Postman where I can login and auth myself fine.

I have to somehow call the token I am getting from logging in, but how I call it I don't know. Hope someone can help!

Been at this for a couple of days now :/

```
# Login

import requests
import json

LoginURL = "https://website.com/Login"

LoginCredentials = {"username":"MYUSERNAME","password":"MYPASSWORD"}

LoginHeaders = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "MYPOSTMANTOKEN"
    }

LoginResponse = requests.request("GET", LoginURL, headers=LoginHeaders,  params=LoginCredentials)

print(LoginResponse.text)


#  Register

RegisterURL = "https://website.com/Register"

RegisterCredentials = {"username":"MYUSERNAME"}

RegisterHeaders = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "MY POSTMAN-TOKEN"
    }

RegisterResponse = requests.request("GET", RegisterURL, headers=RegisterHeaders, params=RegisterCredentials)

print(RegisterResponse.text)
```

Comment: 1) What is the error? 2) Is the authentication set-up with Basic Auth or JWT?

Comment: 1) {
    "Code": -1,
    "Message": null,
    "Result": {
        "Success": false,
        "TextMessage": "Login token error "
    }
} 

2) it inherits auth from parent

Comment: So, this error appears when querying "https://website.com/Register" on Postman? And you're using the auth token from parent i.e., "https://website.com/Login"? Are you using the token from Postman or does the /Login endpoint generate its own access token?

Comment: The /Login endpoint generates an access token, but I don't know how I use this when I register. I uploaded a picture where you can see the code better (https://ibb.co/nxDf5S)

Comment: Right, so this means /resgister is protected with this access token. What you can do is specify a header `Authorization` and give the value as `Bearer your_access_token`. So, on Postman, first select No Auth(instead of inherit from Parent) and then in Headers: `Authorization: Bearer access_token` and `Content-Type: application/json`. Here you should enter the access token you received from /Login endpoint. I also believe that registering a user should be a POST request as opposed to GET(where you are requesting info from server).

Comment: On the picture, I also see a link for the online API documentation for registration, which maybe helpful.

Comment: Let me know if this works.

Comment: I managed to find a solution, but thank you so much for your help anyway! Much appreciated :-) 

From the LoginResponse I was able to parse the Key and Token by using MyKey = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Key'])
MyToken = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Token']) and I added these variables to the register headers RegisterHeaders = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'AOToken': MyToken,
    'AOKey': MyKey,
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

Comment: Great! The official API documentation usually has all the info to query endpoints. These queries may vary from one API to another  based upon the design of the API code. Also, if you have answered your own question, then you should post it as answer and accept it. This would make it easier for others to see the solution and a possible opportunity for you to get upvotes if this issue occurs for someone else. Happy to help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I parsed the Key and Token through

```
MyKey = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Key'])
MyToken = (LoginResponse.json()['Result']['Token'])
```

from the LoginResponse and then added it to the RegisterHeaders

```
RegisterHeaders = {
'accept': "application/json",
'AOToken': MyToken,
'AOKey': MyKey,
'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
}
```